# Bypass login interceptors for certain situations

Tags: spring-security

Is it possible to somehow bypass spring security for certain cases? We are currently using spring security 3.1.x and this setup is working well (form-login, etc).

For our web-api, we now have a requirement that certain objects can be set as 'external' meaning that they should not require login. All objects will be under /api/* but the actual path will be dynamic (usually its /api/{type}/{id}).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

you can define the url pattern in separate http to bypass spring security filter chain, like this

```
 <http pattern="/api/**" security="none"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I know. Sorry for not being clear, the pattern itself will be dynamic, everything under /api/{type}/{id} is locked by default, but the user will be able to change a flag to "externalize" the object, so it will be available directly from /api/example_type/id, but the rest should be locked as before. So I need to 1) check if the user is already logged in, then just go ahead 2) if user it not logged in, then check if the externalized flag is set on the object, and then allow it anyways